# Убрать повторяющиеся значения из массива с учётом общих слов

Tags: php

Обычно массив с уникальными значениями делают так:

```
$arrayInput = array('WHITE','BLACK', 'WHITE');
$uniq = array_unique($arrayInput);
print_r($uniq);
```

На выходе получаем: `Array ( [0] => WHITE [1] => BLACK )`

Но в моём случае есть значения из разряда:

```
$arrayInput = array('WHITE','BLACK', 'WHITE COLOR');
```

Требуется считать значения `'WHITE'` и `'WHITE COLOR'` одинаковыми, потому что в них есть общее слово `WHITE`.

Как реализовать такую проверку уникальности и получить такой же результат `Array ( [0] => WHITE [1] => BLACK )` на выходе?

Comment: функция буквально с таким именем существует в РНР. и если даже лень искать в мануале то поиском находится за 1.5 секунды

Comment: При чем тут лень, $arrayInput = array('WHITE','BLACK', 'WHITE COLOR'); 
$arrayUnique = array_unique($arrayInput);
print_r($arrayUnique); - просто тут все значения уникальны.  Понятно, если массив будет $arrayInput = array('WHITE','BLACK', 'WHITE);  то тут просто. А мне интересен результат на вхождения , чтобы 'white' и 'white color' были одинаковыми.

Comment: @Kirill оформите вопрос соответствующим образом и подробно опишите, по каким критериям элементы должны считаться одинаковыми

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Всё ещё не вижу критериев. Почему `white` и `white color` должны считаться одинаковыми? Если там будет написано `vasya` и `pupkin vasya 123` — это одинаковые или нет?

Comment: верно будут одинаковые. Если переменная  pupkin vasya 123 содержит vasya, то уникальным будет только vasya

Comment: Так каков конкретный критерий? Наличие хотя бы одного общего слова? Или полное вхождение одной строки внутрь другой?

Comment: Верно.. если есть общее слово

Comment: А какая именно строка должна попасть в результирующий массив? Если будет написано `$arrayInput = array('vasya pupkin', 'pupkin vasya');` — какой должен быть результат?

Comment: В моем случае, будет vasya и vasya pupkin, хочу получить vasya. Vasya pupkin и pupkin vasya такого не будет. но чисто теоретически мне любой из этих вариантов подойдёт. главное чтобы он был 1 уникальным.

Comment: Вывожу массив значений из таблицы mysql, distinct делает проверку на уникальность. Но есть значения из разряда : Белый и Белый цвет. Для меня они одинаковые, содержат слово белый.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, поищу с более корректным запросом)